# Is there a way to group by each week in R?

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I have stock data and I want to group by each week and take the average for close and volume. There are 4 consecutive days in each week. Can I do that using dplyr?

```
data<- structure(list(close = c(6.3, 6.25, 5.55, 5.55, 6.4, 6.05, 6.3, 
6.3, 6.7, 6.55), volume = c(140, 100, 1000, 0, 1200, 100, 200, 
0, 100, 400), date = structure(c(13720, 13721, 13724, 13725, 
13726, 13727, 13728, 13731, 13732, 13733), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reformat the date using "%U" or "%V" option to indicate the week number.

```
data %>% group_by(format(date, "%Y%U")) %>%
   mutate(weeklyave=mean(close), weeklyvolume = mean(volume))
```

Comment: Can I reformat the %Y%U vector as (Year-Week)?

Comment: Yes, any unique week and year combination would work, so "%Y-%U", "%y-%V", etc. Note that the last week of the year is not a full 5/7 day week